# Print loss values during training in Keras

Tags: python, keras

How can I print some parameters' values during the Keras training?
I have a custom loss function as:

```
def custom_loss(my_params):
    value_to_be_returned = my_params

    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return something

    return loss
```

How can I print my `value_to_be_returned` during training? Of course, that is a tensor. I tried with:

```
print(K.eval(value_to_be_returned))
```

But when the code is run the tensor is empty and it gets an error.
What I want to see is how my parameter changes during training.

Comment: try print before return,